# CloudKit fetch all subscriptions from the current user

Tags: ios, swift, subscription, cloudkit

I manage to save, change and delete records in Apples CloudKit. I even got notifications working with subscriptions, what I can not find out is, how do i list all subscriptions for the current user.

Here is my code so far:

```
let operation = CKFetchSubscriptionsOperation()
operation.fetchSubscriptionCompletionBlock = { (d, e) -> Void in
    println("got subscription")
    if e != nil {
        println("Error")
        dump(e)
    }
    dump(d)
}
publicDatabase.addOperation(operation)
```

What I got is:

```
got subscription
Error
- <CKError 0x14db0ed0: "Invalid Arguments" (12)> #0
- 0 key/value pairs
```

What are the *Invalid Arguments*? And how do i get a list of all saved subscriptions?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to do something with your subscriptions, then you could use something like this:

```
var database = CKContainer.defaultContainer().publicCloudDatabase
database.fetchAllSubscriptionsWithCompletionHandler({subscriptions, error in
        for subscriptionObject in subscriptions {
            var subscription: CKSubscription = subscriptionObject as CKSubscription
            ..
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much. These lines save my day, Edwin.

Comment: @EdwinVermeer, do yo know how to fetch subscriptions in Objective-C ?

Comment: [privateDatabase fetchAllSubscriptionsWithCompletionHandler:^(NSArray *subscriptions, NSError *error) {
      NSLog(@"Test");
   }];

Comment: Then just loop through the array where you now see the NSLog

Comment: Is it fetching all the subscriptions or all the subscriptions of the current user?

Comment: It's fetching all the subscriptions of the current user

Comment: From my test, corroborated by [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/reference/cloudkitjs/cloudkit.database/1628551-fetchallsubscriptions), this fetches all subscriptions in the schema (i.e. all users). I think you (and I) want to use `fetchAllSubscriptionsOperation`, which can fetch only subscriptions for the current user ([reference](https://developer.apple.com/reference/cloudkit/ckfetchsubscriptionsoperation/1515282-fetchallsubscriptionsoperation)).

Answer (score 3):

I haven't tried this yet but according to the [docs](http://file:///Users/mingsai/Library/Developer/Shared/Documentation/DocSets/com.apple.adc.documentation.iOS.docset/Contents/Resources/Documents/documentation/CloudKit/Reference/CKFetchSubscriptionsOperation_class/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/clm/CKFetchSubscriptionsOperation/c:objc(cs)CKFetchSubscriptionsOperation(cm)fetchAllSubscriptionsOperation); `fetchAllSubscriptionsOperation()` will get all subscriptions for the **user in the current database**, assigning the value of this call to `fetchSubscriptionCompletionBlock` should then work. Adjust the following line of code to:

```
let operation = CKFetchSubscriptionsOperation.fetchAllSubscriptionsOperation()
```

**Quick Help Notes**

[image: fetchAllSubscriptionsOperation]

Again, according to the docs fetchAllSubscriptionsWithCompletionHandler will **fetch all subscriptions on the current database**:

[image: fetchAllSubscriptionsWithCompletionHandler-help]